# How to Create a horizontal Bar Chart using MIM chart library in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios

I created a vertical Bar chart using MIM chart library in xcode (IOS).now i want to create a bar chart in horizontal view using same Mim Chart library.

Is it Possible to create a bar chart in horizontal view? i tried some code but not getting that horizontal view.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with Xcode whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one https://github.com/eul/ILGraphics There is Demo project where you can find how to use it